# Add [vs2013] as a synonym of [visual-studio-2013]

Tags: support, synonym-request, tag-wiki

The synonym in the subject should be created, and [this misuse of tag wikis](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3747968) removed (probably will happen automatically).

Comment: I made sure earlier today that tag vs2013 wouldn't have any questions so it would get cleared at 03:00 UTC. The user who proposed that tag wiki already had my attention for the edit on [tag:hazlecast].

Comment: @rene Yeah, I saw one [pointless wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3747793) also today. Wanted to reject, but unfortunately was approved in the meantime.

Comment: That tag doesn't have question so it will be destroyed this night. His gained rep will not be reverted though.....

Comment: I wanted  to [give this a try](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215258/should-the-gained-reputation-for-a-tag-wiki-be-reverted-if-the-tag-is-removed)

Comment: The tag is still there.

Comment: @It'sNotALie. Yeah, someone used it in a question again. Edited.